# Hats are too awesome for Stack Exchange not to have!

Tags: discussion, shop

I was recently buying stuff from the Stack Exchange shop, and I was looking for something that I was very surprised they didn't have.

## Hats!!!!

[image: Black Stack Overflow Hat] [image: White Stack Overflow Hat]

[image: White Stack Exchange Hat] [image: Black Stack Exchange Hat]

Or something a *little* more intricate:

[image]

I have seen even fairly small companies make hats. Usually, they are the first things that end up in companies shops, and I would have thought Stack Exchange would have already had them. I know if they sold them, at least I would buy one! (or 6)

I think Stack Exchange should start making them!

Does anyone else agree with me?

What about the SE team? What do you think about the idea?

Comment: I would totally buy a hat if they started selling them!!

Comment: Nerds' hair are already messed up enough without the need for hats.

Comment: Maybe StackOverflow doesn't have hats... but then, maybe [SO just isn't good enough for hats.](http://hatdash.com/)

Comment: Hats are awesome. I'd be all over hats. Or they'd be all over me. On my head.

Comment: We need a hat that looks like a cat

Comment: This is a great idea. PayPal is too. They would go very well together, because then I would go buy a matching hoodie, pants and hat. And jacket.

Comment: @yoda Reddit is >> that way >>.

Comment: Ugh, those are fugly.  Better just to go with the site logo without text.

Comment: @Won't - I didn't do the white ones very well, but I though [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tYdKq.png) looked ok...?

Comment: @Ephraim: Eh.  To me, words on hat = suck.  Jin's idea (tho not the style) is better.  The only word that should appear on a SO hat is **[closed]**

Comment: The problem with hats is that “one size fits all” hats don't fit me. Too much boneheadedness I suspect…

Comment: I have a hat - http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/194/chrisf :P

Comment: @ChrisF - Nice! do they give hats to moderators or something?

Comment: @Ephraim - it was in the top user swag pack for DIY.

Comment: There needs to be StackOverflow branded fedoras/tribys, I'd so buy those.

Answer (score 67):

[image: Stack Overflow Top Hat]

^ The only hat I'd consider making... (with optional monocle)

On a more serious note, we don't have any plans for hats.

Comment: Oh c'mon, now that you've gone and tempted us! If not hats, what about visors with affixed unicorn horns?

Comment: Wow, That's awesome! **That** is what you should sell in the shop!! Now I want one!!! Or twelve!!!!! Yes, I'll take twelve!!!! :D

Comment: @TimStone like [this?](http://i.imgur.com/mt2S7.jpg). no.

Comment: @Jin - does Stack Exchange have any plans for changing their mind about getting hats?... (ps, I want one of [those](http://i.imgur.com/mt2S7.jpg) too!!!)

Comment: but more seriously, can I ask why you guys decided not to?

Comment: You needed to have [a model](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3nmJP.png) for this hat.

Comment: hahaha, I meant why did you guys decide not to do [baseball](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tYdKq.png) [style](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2gbdd.png) [hats](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2xiuP.png) [?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XoKw1.png)

Comment: Wow, how did you get a baby picture of Winston Churchill?

Comment: Guess I'll just go back to my [hat simulator](http://www.teamfortress.com) and my [virtual hat](http://steamcommunity.com/id/BoltClock/inventory#440_2_713814566)...

Comment: +1 is for the awesome image, not the lack of hat love :(

Comment: The hat image made me want to create about a dozen sock puppet accounts and earn them some rep to up vote this. But then I saw "no plans" to add hats, and wanted to create about 11 sock puppet accounts and earn them some rep to down vote! So that leaves us with a net of one up vote. ;)

Comment: Jin is a hibster!

Comment: Just ordered one for my [cat](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_-7gz1x_HNjE/SwqdbECEnVI/AAAAAAAAAZQ/a2unootFi_c/s1600/bowler_cat_hat.jpg), thank you!

Answer (score 45):

Only if we can have a hard hat, too.

[image: 'vote to close' Stack Overflow hard hat]

Comment: Now I know exactly what I want for Christmas.

Comment: This is already standard issue for moderators of beta sites.

Answer (score 11):

[We now have hats.](http://winterba.sh/)

Comment: I dunno...wearing a top hat with the Stack Overflow logo on it gets looks.  This gets _over_looked.  Point taken, though.