# Our favorite mod hats

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

Several of our favorite <strike>MSO trolls</strike> mods wear hats or other things on their heads in their user images.

In particular:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

(yes, Shog is in there twice)

As you can see, hats and other head covering things (what is that by the way?! Is that Ylvis?) are a very important part of the identity for some people.

It would be amusing if there were hats that celebrate our favorite mods and their activities.

(No, this isn't to be taken (completely) seriously... though I wouldn't mind a Yannis hat for deleting as many questions as you have delete votes in a 24 hour period.  I would suggest a [Brad Larson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135615/brad-larson) hat, but after the Lions game... maybe for answering a question that gets a [quick run up to 10 points but gets eclipsed by another one that gets 40 points](http://www.nfl.com/gamecenter/2013112800/2013/REG13/packers@lions#menu=highlights&tab=recap))

Comment: My first thought was: "What a total suck-up". But then your moderator related criteria changed my mind. Some of those would be hard hats to get - which is exactly the point of them.

Comment: @slugster, I don't see a hard hat -- why do you tease us so?

Comment: @jmac - I do think you've nailed it, the ultimate groaner: you get a hard hat if you manage to achieve.... several of the *ahem* more difficult hats.

Comment: The hard hat has already been [designed for you.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131902/138112)

Comment: @slugster I looked... I couldn't find any MSO people with a quarter rep greater than 100 who were wearing a hard hat.  I even looked on Home Improvement.SE... though I do find the possibility of a [chrisf](http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/194/chrisf) hat there.

Comment: A note for those who may not know, casperOne is sporting the [official Stack Exchange moderator cap](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JPn7d.jpg).  The eagle-eyed among you may spot other SE mods similarly adorned.

Comment: @BilltheLizard but... what is that on animuson's head?

Comment: @MichaelT Some kind of furry/Catwoman costume, I think.

Comment: Clearly it is not a hat. I am a kitty. :P

Comment: @animuson i always thought that those are evil horns x-: sorry;( i just realized today it was ears of a cat. :P

Comment: Not a mod but long time and high rep user: [BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) with cool hat and even a parrot!

Comment: @animuson I'm still picturing you going around asking "[what does the fox say?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jofNR_WkoCE)" (yes, its a link to that youtube video for those not familiar with the context)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Doesn't count. BalusC is the parrot in the picture, not the human.

Comment: nobody likes hats.

Comment: @Yannis: [The associated Meta account](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138231/chichiray) says the opposite.

Comment: @MichaelT anyone not familiar with that video should be banned from teh interwebs.